# Presto sql join vs intersect-union which one is more performance efficient

Tags: sql, join, presto, trino

Problem statement:

`process_name` is 'test.exe' and registry_key is `\\REGISTRY\\test` and ip is `192.x.x.x`.

Schema:

```
process_name is in process table
registry_key is in registry table
ip is in network table
process_id is common across all tables
```

Each table size is around 500 GB, data is in s3 in orc format. I am querying data by creating hive external table, and using **presto** as processing engine.

I can solve above problem by following approaches

1. using union-intersection

   ```
   SELECT process_id
   FROM   process_table
   WHERE  process_name = 'test.exe'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT process_id
   FROM   registry_table
   WHERE  registry_key = '\\REGISTRY\\test'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT process_id
   FROM   network_table
   WHERE  ip = '192.x.x.x'
   ```
2. using join

   ```
   SELECT process_table.process_id
   FROM   process_table
          INNER JOIN registry_table
                ON process_table.process_id = registry_table.process_id
          INNER JOIN network_table
                ON process_table.process_id = network_table.process_id
   WHERE  process_name = 'test.exe'
          AND registry_key = '\\REGISTRY\\test'
          AND ip = '192.x.x.x'
   ```

Both return the same result; I want to know which one is more efficient - join or intersect-union ?

Answer (score 1):

Question about efficiency is not relevant.

It your particular case INTERSECT and INNER JOIN can return the same dataset, but in general these two are completely different:

- INNER JOIN will not return rows with NULLs in join keys, INTERSECT will return NULLs.
- INNER JOIN will produce duplicated rows if join key is duplicated, as a result you can have more rows than it was in the biggest table.
- INTERSECT will remove full duplicates and as a result you can have less rows than it was in the smallest table.

Comment: for above given case which approach will execute faster, Can you tell that ?

Comment: @AbhiK . . . You are missing the point of this answer.  The *results* from the two are different.  You should use the version that is semantically what you want.  Your question  is not sufficiently constrained to say the results are the same.

Comment: @AbhiK check the EXPLAIN command and measure the execution time. I bet for INNER JOIN if you have no duplicates because it does not care about distinct and joins by only limited number of keys

Comment: @AbhiK And in case of duplication INNER JOIN may work slower because duplication can significantly increase the number of rows

Comment: @AbhiK This question is like what is more efficient: commit or rollback...